# Netbeans Cannot start Java DB server (MAC)

Tags: jsp, netbeans, derby

I am trying to start Java DB thru netbeans on my mac. I am getting following error:

```
Thu Sep 05 21:47:23 EST 2013 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security     
policy.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:600)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.acceptsURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:248)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:273)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.startNetworkServer(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:706)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:70)
... 7 more
```

all the configuration folder are in right place. 
[image]

Cannot figure out what happened.

Comment: You have a better chance of solving it by re-installing Netbeans. If that failed, the JDK and JRE. Some problems are better solved using heuristics rather than reason.

Comment: i tried reinstalling netbeans but no luck. I am a student and my lecturer wants me to do my project on netbeans for some reason.

Comment: In that case, uninstall the JDK, and JRE and re-install them from the Oracle site. Neteabeans is easy easy  to use once you resolve the issue so don't hate it  :)

Comment: @Aradom thanks mate ended up installing Netbeans 7.3.1 fixed everything. appreciate your help buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried every option but can't figure out what happened. So to fix this problem i install Netbeans 7.3.1. It works like a charm.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check your glassfish version. It should match netbeans. With netbeans 7.3.1, the root shoud be `Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.0/javadb`